# How to make image rotate with a button click in Swift 3/4?

Tags: ios, swift

so I am creating an app in Swift 4. I have logo on my main screen, which I put a button on it. But, I try to implement when you click on the logo it should rotate, but for some reason, it is not rotating. Can you see what is wrong?

Here is my code

```
    class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var logoClicked: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    @IBAction func logoClickTapped(_ sender: Any) {

      rotateAnyView(view: logoClicked, fromValue: 0, toValue: Float(2.0 * M_PI), duration: 1)



    }

  func rotateAnyView(view: UIView, fromValue: Double, toValue: Float, duration: Double = 1) {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    animation.duration = duration
    animation.fromValue = fromValue
    animation.toValue = toValue
    view.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
  }

}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959523/swift-rotate-gesture-and-rotation-increments-of-90-degrees/

Comment: @matt When tapping on the image, nothing happens

Comment: Just make sure your outlet to logoClicked and action logoClickTapped 
 are properly connected to the storyboard

Comment: Please see my answer. Fix your keyPath and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. I'm guessing that you forgot to hook up the IBAction to the button. Set a breakpoint in your `logoClickTapped` function and make sure it's being called.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your keyPath. For example z rotation. `

```
func rotateAnyView(view: UIView, fromValue: Double, toValue: Float, duration: Double = 1) {
   let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
   animation.duration = duration
   animation.fromValue = fromValue
   animation.toValue = toValue
   view.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If ImageView is the one you want to rotate by 90 degrees then.

ImageView.transform = ImageView.transform.rotated(CGFloat.pi/2)